# Sort nested array by content

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a data structude ST that contains an array of entities of ST.

```
struct ST {
    ST[];
}
```

I need to sort it by deep-value.

For example i have an array of ST: [A { B, C, D }, B { C, D }, C, D { E }, E, F]

And i want to get result like this: [E, D, C, B, E, F, A]

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Maybe, if you explain how to get to the result.

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on what language you are using however the basic idea remains the same. The idea is that each struct can have a value assigned which can then be used for sorting.

A similar question was asked here: [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

I hope this helps, but generally you should try asking questions in greater detail